# Pasting Excel Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to paste my Excel chart to a PowerPoint slide using different options available in 'Paste Special' command of VBA.

I am not getting any option through which I could '*paste chart with Embed data in a sheet*'

I used the `ppPasteOLEObject` but that embeds the entire Excel workbook due to which the size of the PowerPoint file increases.

```
Sub excltoppt()

Dim ppalApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppalPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppalSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppalApp = New PowerPoint.Application

ppalApp.Visible = True
ppalApp.Activate

Set ppalPres = ppalApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.pptx")

Set ppalSlide = ppalPres.Slides(6)

'here it select data from specific excel sheet #6    
Sheets("S06").Select
Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Copy

'here it paste at the selected specific slide #6
ppalSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteText
'ole object option that I have tried is:-
'ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject

End Sub
```

I tried to use this option but it is also not working:

```
PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartDestinationTheme")
```

I am using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, this pastes the chart into your slide, just not sure how to go about making it have embedded data:

```
Sub excltoppt()

Dim ppalApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppalPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppalSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set ppalApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    ppalApp.Visible = True

    Set ppalPres = ppalApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.pptx")

    Set ppalSlide = ppalPres.Slides(6)

    Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Copy

    ppalSlide.Shapes.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sheets("S06").Select
Worksheets("S06").ChartObjects(1).Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
ppaslide.select
ppalApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste

For x = 1 To ppalSlide.Shapes.Count
    If ppalSlide.Shapes(x).HasChart Then
        ppalSlide.Shapes(x).LinkFormat.BreakLink
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed Hassan, Hi Xabier,

Thanks for your comments, both of your options are working for me and it gives me an embeded chart. But the thing is that they connect back to the Workbook from where excel chart has been pasted.

And after completing the Macro process it deletes those temp files. Henceforth if I now tries to edit data in Powerpoint chart it gives the following error message:-
"The linked file is not available. To edit the link, click the file tab. Click the info tab, and then under related documents, click edit links to Files."

Comment: And if I follow the message given in Error message and 'Break Link' then edit option in chart become invisible.

Comment: Now check i replaced it with image

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for your quick support, but this is giving me an image of Chart.
I am looking for a code which could create a chart with embedded data only like to we have when we create a chart in powerpoint itself.